# cannot get pip to be recognized as a command

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install **matplotlib** into **python27** but am running into issues with pip. As stated when I try any 'pip' command I get

> 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I checked my path variables and they point to the location of my OSGeo4W Python27 install. `get-pip.py` works and it even says I am up to date on my pip install.

I am wondering if the issue is that I have more than one Python installed on my PC. Arc Desktop decided I needed **C:\Python27** and **C:\Python34** on top of the OSGeo4W install in the **C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27**

Anyone know what the issue might be?
Can I consolidate my python installs without breaking anything?

Comment: The pip executable is not in your path. Multiple installations shouldn't have anything to do with that. Make sure that the path contains the directory with the pip executable.

Comment: The path to the exe is there for the OSGeo4W install, and I have since discovered that pip works through the OSGeo4W shell but not the windows cmd. Maybe I need to add paths to the pip.exe for both the C:\Python27 and C:\Python34 for it to work in the windows cmd?

Comment: Try `python -m pip` instead.

Comment: You can also try `import pip` from within the Python interpreter.  If it can't find it you know it's not there for the install you're running.  If it *can* run it that way but not from the command line then your Python path is right but your system path is wrong.

Comment: Since you have both versions of python try specifics like `pip2` or `pip3` !

Comment: It started working when I restarted the cmd so I must have fixed it when I added the paths but didn't realize cmd needed a restart in order to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `C:\Python27\Scripts` to your path as well. That is where the pip executable lives by default.

Also, remember to close and reopen your command shell after you change your path variable to make sure that the update is loaded.

Comment: Yeah! That was it, I added the paths but didn't restart the cmd; after I opened the OSGeo4W shell and it was working. Just reopened my cmd and it seems to be working there now too. After all of that though I cannot install matplotlib with pip in windows apparently. The whl files they provide for some reason are not recognized by python. Oh well atleast I don't have to go through all this later when I want to install something else into python. 
Thanks!

Comment: I've got it installed on Windows in python27. I think I downloaded the whl file from this site: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib It has builds for multiple architectures. Just download the one that suites your configuration.

Comment: And thank you again the whl file I got from there worked.

Comment: If this answered the question then you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).